# mysqld started but default-values are not used

Tags: mariadb, my.cnf

[image: mysqld would be started with max_connections=100 but the value is not used]

Hello,
in the /etc/mysql/my.cnf I configured all those proberties but not any of them is used.

Like you see for example max_connections=100 is defined as default but the max_connections value stays at 151.

Can anybody say why?

Comment: Is `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` word writeable? If it is MySQL will ignore it.

Comment: The rights for the my.cnf are 644. Owner root:root. is this okay?

Answer (score 0):

I think you did this:

1. Had `max_connections = 151;` in my.cnf (the default)
2. `SET GLOBAL max_connections = 100;`
3. (as shown) restarted `mysqld`, thereby losing the 100 and reestablishing the 151.
4. (as shown) saw 151.

`SET GLOBAL` does not persist past a restart of mysqld.  Permanent changes need be put into my.cnf.  (Meanwhile, you can temporarily set things with `SET GLOBAL`.)